# Would 'gem update --system' make my previously installed gems incompatible?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I tried to install hoe and I encounted this:

> Installing hoe (2.9.1)
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in
>   `install': hoe requires RubyGems
>   version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update
>   --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)

I am now worried the update might corrupt my previous installed gems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gem update --system` will only update rubygems itself.

Previously installed gems are not affected and should run just like before.

Or is there a specific gem or situation you are worried about?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading RubyGems won't affect previously installed Gems.